# Ansibe: concatenation of items from with_items

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get a variable which will contain comma separated items from `with_itmes` loop as follow:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: set_fact
      set_fact:
        foo: "{{ foo }}{{ item }},"
      with_items:
        - "one"
        - "two"
        - "three"
      vars:
        foo: ""

    - name: Print the var
      debug:
        var: foo
```

It works as expected but what I'm getting at the end is trailing comma.

Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `join` filter that we can use with lists to concatenate list elements with a given character.

If we are passing the list directly to `with_items` or `loop` then we can use [loop_control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) to "*extend*" some more loop information to get `ansible_loop.allitems`. Then this can be joined with the `join` filter.

Example:

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      foo: "{{ ansible_loop.allitems|join(',') }}"
    loop:
    - one
    - two
    - three
    loop_control:
      extended: true
```

Otherwise a more straightforward way is to define a variable with list and use `join` filter on elements of that variable.

Example:

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      foo: "{{ mylist|join(',') }}"
    vars:
      mylist:
      - one
      - two
      - three
```

Answer (score 0):

No clue if this is correct way to do but it does the job:

```
    - name: Print the var
      debug:
        msg: "LIST: {{ foo | regex_replace(',$','') }}"
```

Comment: If we use the `join` filter, we wouldn't have to worry about the trailing comma.